# Physics Review Journals Ordering Authors and Group Affiliations Question

Tags: author, author-number, affiliation

In the environment that is included in the tex sample file from PR, we find:

```
 \documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,pre]{revtex4-1}
```

In here we directly use things like

```
\title{My Title}
\author{Author1}
\email{Email1}
\affiliation{Univ1}

\author{Author2}
\email{Email2}
\affiliation{Univ2}

\author{Author3}
\email{Email3}
\affiliation{Univ1}
\altaffiliation{Univ2}
```

But this breaks the order of authors like so:

[image]

I want something that looks like say the newest editor's suggestion on PRE:
https://journals.aps.org/pre/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevE.99.062406, a snapshot of title page and authors:

[image]

I do want authors ordered as A1, A2, A3 with the affiliations numbered and listed at the bottom.

Would you please help? This should be a standard question with standard answers. I'm new to this journal so trying to correctly style things out

Comment: what do you mean by break the order? It would be easier to understand if your example was a complete small document and you said how you wanted the output to change. (You can mark code sections by highlighting then using the `{}` button (which indents by four spaces) I did it already for your current fragments.)

Comment: The link you give is not public.

Comment: Thanks David, will make some edits according to your suggestions.